# How To Group Multiple Row As Single Row

Tags: sql

I have a table `emp` has the following data:

```
id name phone no
---------------------
1 smith 423-422-5226
1 smith 414-255-5252
2 george 511-522-2525
2 george 524-522-2428
```

I need the output as:

```
1 smith 423-422-5226, 414-255-5252
2 george 511-522-2525, 524-522-2428
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: In sql server u can do using xml path

Comment: Hi @satindersingh.. can you give an example how to do this in sql server with xml path

Answer (score 6):

Since you didn't specify what RDBMS you are using, let me assume you are using SQL Server from your tags. Then you can use [`FOR XML`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178107%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) to do so, like this:

```
SELECT 
  t1.Id,
  t1.name
  STUFF((
    SELECT ', ' + t2.phone_no
    FROM Table1 t2
    WHERE t2.ID   = t1.ID
      AND t2.Name = t1.Name
    FOR XML PATH (''))
  ,1,2,'') AS PhoneNumbers
FROM Table1 t1
GROUP BY t1.Id, 
         t1.Name;
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9cb15/3)

This will give you:

```
| ID |   NAME |               PHONENUMBERS |
--------------------------------------------
|  1 |  smith | 423-422-5226, 414-255-5252 |
|  2 | george | 511-522-2525, 524-522-2428 |
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done with,

```
**GROUP_CONCAT() for MYSQL,NETEZZA
WM_CONCAT() for ORACLE**
```

Here is your query

```
select id,name, group_concat(phoneno) phoneno
from emp 
group by id,name
```

Use accordingly to your databse

[**SQLLiveDemo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98a89/1)

Sample Output,

```
ID  NAME    PHONENO
1   smith   423-422-5226,414-255-5252
2   george  511-522-2525,524-522-2428
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have at most two rows per name, you can do:

```
select id, name, min(phone_no), max(phone_no)
from emp
group by id, name
```

If you have more phone numbers and want to concatenate them into a single field, you need an aggregation string concatenation function.  How you do this depends on the dialect and version of SQL that you are using.

Comment: There is an article here for a CLR solution for string concat. Google  I haved used something similar but cant find the code now: http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1691/sql-server-clr-function-to-concatenate-values-in-a-column/

Comment: Thank you, that helped my with another issue I was facing.

Answer (score 0):

```
select a.id, a.name, a.phoneno, b.phoneno
from emp a
left join emp b on a.id = b.id and a.name = b.name and a.phoneno <> b.phoneno
```

Answer (score 0):

Tobias Ternstrom at Microsoft has a workaround that works for sql server2005 and higher: 
Consider the following example using the AdventureWorks microsoft sample database:

```
 SELECT 
        soh.OrderDate
        ,(
            SELECT 
                p.Name + ', '
            FROM Production.Product AS p
            INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderDetail AS sod ON p.ProductID = sod.ProductID
            WHERE sod.SalesOrderID = soh.SalesOrderID
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
         ).value('/', 'NVARCHAR(max)') AS ProductsOrdered
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader AS soh
```

See where they discuss the same problem here: 
[string aggregate function, something like SUM for numbers](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/389883/string-aggregate-function-something-like-sum-for-numbers)